# Seleção única de RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobutton

Olá, gostaria de pedir ajuda sobre a seleção única de um RadioButton, inseri dois na minha página e eu gostaria que apenas 1 pudesse ser selecionado, caso o outro fosse marcado desmarcasse automaticamente o outro...

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 radiobutton">
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioBtnPar" runat="server" Text="Par" OnCheckedChanged="RadioBtnPar_CheckedChanged"/>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioBtnImpar" runat="server" Text="Ímpar" OnCheckedChanged="RadioBtnImpar_CheckedChanged"/>
        </div>
```

[image: Assim que fica, mas quero o que comentei acima]

```
 protected void RadioBtnPar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioBtnImpar.AutoPostBack = true;
    RadioBtnImpar.Checked = false;
}

protected void RadioBtnImpar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioBtnPar.Checked = false;
}
```

Aqui está os comandos do evento de checkedchanged, obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escolher entre vários `RadioButton`, eles precisam ter o mesmo nome no html (por exemplo `name="parimpar"`)

Como está usando o controle do `asp-net`, use a propriedade `GroupName`, por exemplo `GroupName="ParImpar"` em todos os radiobutton, que ficará assim no html:

```html
<input type="radio" ID="RadioBtnPar" name="ParImpar" />Par  
<input type="radio" ID="RadioBtnImpar" name="ParImpar" />Ímpar
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tinha usado antes o name="", porém não sabia que era somente HTML, agora está funcionando, brigadão mesmo!!!